# Is it possible to use more than one Babel preset in a project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs, expo

I am developing a React-Native app, which was installed using [Expo](https://expo.io), that creates .babelrc config with this code:

```
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
        }
    }
}
```

Recently I have encountered 2 other libraries that require the installation of other types of babel presets named: `"react-native"` and `"flow"`.

**Question:** How can I merge 3 presets?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add them as items to the array of presets

```
{
    "presets": ["babel-preset-expo","react-native","flow"]
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
        }
    }
}
```